# How to detect BLINKS using OpenCV for Android?

Tags: android, opencv, feature-detection

What is the best way to detect blinks from an up close image of an eye? I am getting the frames from a head mounted camera as shown before.

[image: Eye Open]

[image]

I have tried:

*Template Matching* which doesnt always give accurate results.

*Looking for frames in which the pupil is not visible* - also not always accurate.

Comment: Can you understand the reasons why templateMatching and pupilDetection fails sometimes?

Comment: can you further describe what feature is used for template matching?

Comment: I was using this link for template matching.
http://www.technolabsz.com/2013/05/eye-blink-detection-using-opencv-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use HoughTransform for circle detection. 
it returns a list of circles found in the image.
the first circle in the list should be the pupil.
then if the list is empty or the circle found is smaller then x pixels the eye is closed.

Comment: I've already tried looking for frames in which the pupil is not visible as mentioned. However this is not always accurate as circles are detected anyway(due to eyelashes etc).

Comment: that is the reason you need to check the size.

Comment: you will need to test it to see what size the eye should be and then go through the list and check each element if it fits.

Comment: ilan - have you done this successfully with images this close to the eye?

Comment: i haven't done a blink detector, but i have made a pupil center location finder.